# Computing integral involving derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to evaluate an expression $\int_C g(\nabla f)ds$.

This is an integration along a curve $C$ in a plane given as a function of some parameter $s$:

```
c[s_]:={..., ...}
```

The function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is given by some expression:

```
g[{x_,y_}]:=...
```

and the function on the plane $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is also given by some expression:

```
f[{x_,y_}]:=...
```

How do I write the integral in Mathematica notation?

The problem I'm having is that when I try to substitute the two components of `c[s]` for `x` and `y` in `Grad[f[{x, y}], {x, y}]` it messes up the variables with respect to which the derivative is being taken.

In particular, how to I substitute the components of `c` for `x` and `y` after the derivative is computed and do so in a way that leaves an expression suitable for integration? I want to evaluate this entire things as one expression.

Comment: `f[{x_, y_}] := x x;
g[{x, y}] := Grad[f[{x, y}], {x, y}];
r[t_] := {t, t};
Integrate[
 Evaluate[g[{x, y}] /. Thread[{x, y} :> Evaluate@r[t]]] Norm[r'[t]],
  t]`